# How to create PR to master when another branch was created first?

Tags: git, github

I created an empty repository on Github platform. I cloned it and checkout to another branch (let's say `develop`). Then I committed changes and pushed the code from `develop` to Github (`git push origin develop`). However, I forgot to create `master` branch to do the Pull Request (PR). So I decided to checkout to `master` branch, removed all the code, and pushed the empty branch to Github. I encountered a problem when I tried to create PR:

> **There isn’t anything to compare.**
>
> master is up to date with all commits from develop. Try switching the base for your comparison.
>
> **No commit comments for this range**

Is there any solution to that? How can I create PR from `develop` branch to the empty branch?

Comment: If you started with an empty repo, why not just create the master branch off the tip of develop? Or if you want to utilize PRs, rebase develop onto the empty master branch? You can't merge branches that do not have a common ancestor, they have nothing in common otherwise.

Comment: What's the point of a PR if that's the only code in the repo? Just push it to master.

Comment: I just would like someone to review already pushed code

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
git checkout --orphan master
git push --force origin master
```

This should create an empty master branch, which won’t be based on `develop`, hence `develop` will have something to merge into master.